# UK Foundation - initial practical assessment, what to expect?

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm going to be starting the Foundation course in the next few weeks, and have been offered an initial practical assessment at a member's shack to save time for the club during the course.

The call to be made is on 2m with a QSY, so I'm wondering how that will pan out and what to expect?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Did you read official descriptions of the assessment from RSGB? I did read some articles describing the practical assessment several months ago, so I'll try to post links if I find them again. My general impression was that it's nothing scary. Remember, the experienced, licensed member of the club is there to make sure you don't make any serious mistakes. The non-serious mistakes are normal and to be expected and are part of process of getting experience!

Comment: By the way, I found a recording of the 2 m QSO you might need to do [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sikp-RboRZA).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @AndrejaKo, much appreciated. You were right, the instructor was there to assist and made it all very clear and simple to follow. Also appreciate the recording of the whole process you linked to. If it were in answer form I'd have approved it, but as it stands, many thanks. 73

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer this question myself at this point as I've just completed the practical last night.

@AndrejaKo provided a perfect example of the whole exercise in his video clip. Thanks also to the Essexham channel for that information.

It was simply a matter of:

- Calling CQ on the VHF calling frequency 145.500.
- Finding a clear frequency, checking it's clear then reporting that back to correspondent on calling frequency, requesting a QSY (frequency change) to the new frequency (using their call sign first each time before your own)
- Checking signal reports and QTH (location) with correspondent on new frequency and then finally clearing the frequency

You get an almost scripted sheet from your instructor, if you're lucky, as per the video and my own experience, and then you are guided through the call. It's just to show you can use the controls on a basic VHF set.

If you've been listening to any ham calls at all you'll be familiar with the format of the conversations. I went first, my associate second. I have been listening in for a year or more so was quite comfortable, if a little nervous at my first contact. He got through it just fine with no prior experience, obviously with a few more nerves from being bombarded by dozens of new and unfamiliar terms. But went over no trouble.

Hope that helps any new hams-to-be in the future.

Comment: Nice to see that you followed up your question with an answer. Just don't forget to accept it when you can! Otherwise, it will stay as unanswered here in the system and that is not so good.