# How do I get a license without being near a club?

Tags: license, united-kingdom

I don't have a radio club near me, and as far as I'm aware I can't get an amateur radio license without being at a club to do the tests. Is there a way I can get an amateur radio license?

I have done some reading and I can't find anything specific; all I get is dead end links or Find A Club. I can't really travel far either so I can't get to a club. I live in the north east of England.

Comment: Hello! Please try to help us help you. Using correct punctuation and capitalization makes your question more readable and increases the probability of it attracting a useful answer. Furthermore, when writing a question, try to place yourself in our shoes. How am I supposed to know where in the world are you exactly? Perhaps it's a bit strange, but the exam regulations are region-specific and if I tell you the solution from my region, it's very likely it won't solve your problem. If you want good answers, please do try to provide relevant information in the question body itself.

Comment: Sorry i barely passed English so i do apologize for the bad Grammar. I live in the north east of England. I will update the question with this.

Comment: OK, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're not going to like the answer, because it does seem to boil down to: Find a club.

From what I can gather, the exams are done by RSGB so you'll need to schedule an examination date at one of the clubs and go there to take the exam. There's a list of examination locations here: https://thersgb.org/services/coursefinder/
From what I can see, you don't need to actually go to a course, if you can learn everything on your own or if you want to take an online course. You just need to appear for the exam.

The exams have two parts:
The practical part is very easy (or at least that's how it looks to me), you don't have to do it at the same time as the theoretical part and the results are valid for a year. We already have a question about that here: [UK Foundation - initial practical assessment, what to expect?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/5304/77) It appears that you don't actually have to go to a club to do it, you can do it from assessor's location. There's a practical part for the Foundation license and there's a practical part for the Intermediate license, but you can do both at the same time, if you want.

Then there's the written part as well, for which you'll need the practical assessment certificate. From what I can see, you'll need to appear for that part at an examination center.

If you can't move for some reason, perhaps it would be a good idea to contact RSBG and see what they can tell you about that. On [this](http://rsgb.org/main/clubs-training/for-students/foundation/) page, there's the telephone number of their examinations department. Perhaps it's possible to come to some sort of an arrangement, if you're immobile.

Comment: Thank you, i will arrange to stay with family down south who go to a club and ill apply to do the course online first. My nearest club is about an hour away so ill just take a trip away to see family and knock 2 birds with 1 stone.

Comment: @Ryan white Good luck with the exam and be sure to post more questions, if anything is unclear.